# How to show flash message after ajax success in laravel?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I want to show a flash message after redirect to view by ajax request.

Here is my controller code

```
    \Session::flash('success', __('Password change successfully. Please Login again')); 
     $data            = array();
     return response()->json([
          'success' => true,
          'data'    => $data,
        ]);
```

Here is my ajax request

```
  $.ajax({
   url: my-url
   method: "POST",
   data: new FormData(this),
   contentType: false,
   cache: false,
   processData: false,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(response) {
    if (response.success == true) {
      var url ="{{ route('admin.dashboard') }}"; //the url I want to redirect to
            $(location).attr('href', url);
    }  
}, //success end

});
```

It redirects to my blade view where I use below code to show a flash message

```
   @if (session()->has('success'))
       <div class="alert alert-success alert-solid alert-dismissible shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 rounded" 
          role="alert">
          {{ session('success') }}
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
     </div>
  @endif
```

But it didn't show any message.

Can anyone tell me the way how to show a flash message?

Answer (score 2):

`\Session::flash` works for only the next request. That means you can't get its value after one refresh of the page or after one redirect. The case may be you are facing is you are putting the flash data then through ajax call you are getting it back then again you are redirecting it to another page/URL. Try the `reflash()` method. It will help you to keep the data for the next few requests.

```
\Session::flash('success', __('Password change successfully. Please Login again'));
\Session::reflash(); // add this line
```

For more info: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session#flash-data